# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' 10

Tags: c#

I keep getting error "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'" in C#.

Following is my code that is getting error

```
    public static void CreateOpcItems()
    {
        RsiOPCAuto.OPCItems lclItems;
        lclItems = opcGroup.OPCItems;

        globalOpcItem[1] = lclItems.AddItem("[Orex_Brain_Mill2]gStnMill2.DATA.MillTemperature", 1);



    }
    public static object GetPlcValue(string pItem)
    {

        object lclObject = new object();
        globalOpcItem[pItem].Read(1, lclObject);

    }
```

Comment: What is not clear in the error message?

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you're trying to use a `string` as an index to a collection (`globalOpcItem`), when it needs to be an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

you may either change your function to accept int:

```
public static object GetPlcValue(int pItem)
{

    object lclObject = new object();
    globalOpcItem[pItem].Read(1, lclObject);

}
```

or parse it:

```
public static object GetPlcValue(string pItem)
{

    object lclObject = new object();
    globalOpcItem[int.Parse(pItem)].Read(1, lclObject);

}
```

Comment: The second  approach is brittle - if the string isn't an int, the `int.Parse` method will throw a format exception (or something similar).  Better option is #1; for the second I'd add more code and use `Int.TryParse` for more resilience.

Comment: @Tim, well I know it, but I want to suggest the possible solutions, if `pItem` is a number in string format he will need to parse it anyway, either before sending it to function or in it. and even if it's not parseable using `TryParse` may avoid errors but will give an incorrect answer

Comment: An incorrect answer to the OP's question, or an incorrect answer in the data retrieval?  `TryParse` would allow the code to error out gracefully and not try and retrieve data in the case of a non-integer string, rather than throwing an exception that may or may not be caught at a higher level.

Comment: I have already tried these all methods then another error is coming like

Comment: The error is "No overload for method 'Read' takes 2 arguments"

Comment: @LasithaFernando this is not related to this question. you should check how many and which types of arguments `Read()` takes.